# To translate truth table into English and decipher logical argument it makes

Tags: propositional-calculus

This is from How to prove it by Velleman.

It will either rain or snow tomorrow.

It is too warm to snow.

Therefore, it will rain.

Let P - It will rain tomorrow,  Q - It will snow tomorrow; representing the argument symbolically,

$P \vee Q$

$\neg Q$

$\therefore P$

[image]

The last line reads as "It will rain tomorrow OR it will snow tomorrow.  It will snow tomorrow.  Therefore, it will rain."  I did not understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading here 
$$(P \vee Q) \wedge \neg Q \Rightarrow P.$$

In English, "Either $P$ is true or $Q$ is true, and $Q$ is false, therefore $P$ is true." This corresponds with line 3 of your truth table. I hope that was useful in some way. Do tell if further clarification is desired.

Comment: negation of Q is False, therefore Q is true

Comment: I remember hearing as an undergrad of a few people missing the true/false question: $(Q \wedge\neg Q)$. Always false of course.

Comment: ouch!!!!!!!! I got it !!! :) thanx